# Difficulty w/ Directives with optional scope values and setting with literals in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

New to angular.  Trying to understand the proper way to do things

I am trying to create a directive that will run custom logic when a user clicks on a link before moving to the next page.  However, before I can even get to the custom logic I'm having difficulty setting up the directive. I want to be able to:

A) Have certain attributes on the directive be optional (set to different defaults in certain cases)

B) Have a user be able to pass a string literal OR a variable from the controller's scope into the directive's attributes to be used on the directive's scope.

My Problems:

1.) If I use string literals in the directive's attributes, the corresponding $scope property is undefined.  I have to access it through the $attrs.  This isn't the worst thing but seems like a wrong practice to have to check the $scope.Prop and if it is undefined check $attrs.Prop.

2.) Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17200559/125275) seems to say I need to use single quote when using string literals in the attributes but that behavior does not work in my example.

3.) When I have certain attributes on the directive not set, the default value I set on the $scope in the 'controller' function on the directive is not reflected when rendered.  I cannot figure out why.

[Code in Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pgP9eqD6uPW1PqIQwJsR)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I was able to get my example using Sylvain's answer.  Here is a fixed version for future reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/4eKR7iGuVeVhoL5mrLni

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RB6shHI0xYa1FkP4eXDy) is a version where all three cases work:

1. The literals work without anything special
2. The scope values work using the usual `{{ expression }}` syntax
3. Defaults are provided in the directive's template using this syntax `href='{{strHref || 'default href'}}'` which I found in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Wmzp6OU4IRc).

Here is the full directive definition:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        strHref: '@link',
        strText: '@displayText',
    },
    template: '<div><div>variables: {{strHref || \'default href\'}}, {{strText || \'default text\'}}</div> result: <a href="{{strHref || \'default href\'}}">{{strText || \'default text\'}}<span ng-show="blnIsBackButton"> (Return)</span></a></div>',

};
```

Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/RB6shHI0xYa1FkP4eXDy

Comment: I'm sorry. I've just realized I pasted the wrong links. I had a plunker sample ready! I know it's too late but I edited my answer with the right links.

Answer (score 0):

Scope & can be used for literals /expression. Scope = for setting up 2 way binding and scope = for method call.
You can set default value for property in controller if you want

I think directive name has to be lower case. Can someone confirm this? If i use pageLink it does not work but works for pagelink. (note 'L'). Same for property.

There are some nice videos about scope in http://www.egghead.io/.

I created this in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5sBoo3) which uses all 3 scope isolation types

Comment: You can define your directive with camelCase (`pageLink`) but in the HTML you need to use snake case: `page-link` or `page:link` or `page_link`.  There are a few other snake case options, see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.